# How to make a neural net give position?

Tags: image, machine-learning, position, theory

I understand how to do classification problems and starting to understand convolution networks which I think is the answer to some extent. I'm a bit confused on how to setup a network to give me the output position.

Let's say you have the position of the end point of noses for a data set with faces. To find the end point do you just do a 'classification' type problem where your output layer is something like 64x64 = 4096 points but if the nose is at point row 43 and column 20 of your grid you just set the output as all zero's except for at element 43*64 + 20 = 2772 where you set it equal to 1? Then just map it back to your image dimensions.

I can't find much info on how this part of identification works and this is my best guess. I'm working towards a project at the second with this methodology, but it is going to be a lot of work and want to know if I'm at least on the right track. This seems to be a solved problem, but I just can't seem to find how people do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although what you describe could feasibly work, generally neural networks (convolutional and otherwise) are not used to determine the position of a feature in an image.  In particular, Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNs) are specifically designed to be translation invariant so that they will detect features regardless of their position in the input image - this is sort of the inverse of what you're looking for.

One common and effective solution for the kind of problem you're describing is a cascade classifier.  They have some limitations, but for the kind of application you're describing, it would probably work quite well.  In particular, cascade classifiers are designed to provide good performance owing to the staged approach in which most sections of the input image are very quickly dismissed by the first couple stages.

Don't get me wrong, it may be interesting to experiment with using the approach you described; just be aware that it may prove difficult to get it to scale well.

Comment: My reading papers seem to indicate they use regression based methodologies after looking into it more. Essentially have the neural network to calculate the positions and use convolution nets for non-linear effects on the calculation. 

I was going to try facial landmark recognition and there is a lot of work in that area where they get pretty darn good results with just neural networks and are slightly less finicky then cascade classifiers. I'm definitely looking at cascade classifiers also though, thinking of using a two staged attack with them and neural nets.

Comment: A two-staged approach works out pretty well in my experience.  Basically, I use a cascade classifier to first identify possible locations of the target feature, then I use the more expensive neural net inference to gain confidence in one of those identified locations.  And generally, for the neural net, I use CNNs since the convolutional layers provide a convenient way to extract important features from the image without too much manual pre-processing.

Comment: My one issue with cascade classifiers is that they seem very finicky going by the ones in opencv. Is it possible to train some that are not rotationally variant and work from multiple angles? Or is it necessary to run several passes with many classifiers for multiple angles to make sure you catch the faces?

Comment: It's definitely true that cascade classifiers can be finicky, but they fill an important role in reducing the computational expense of problems like you're describing.  Depending on how much data you collect, and the quality of the data, it's possible to train a cascade classifier that is fairly robust to variations in the data.  In my experience, it's very difficult to attain accuracy approaching 100% positive detection and 0% false positives, but assuming it's just the first stage of your pipeline, you can lower the detection threshold and then dispense with false positives using a CNN.

Comment: Thanks man very helpful. I'll look into training the cascade classifiers a bit more also. Pretty new to OpenCV so stumbling through to try and figure stuff out.